# How do I perform a (first-order) Taylor expansion on $\frac{f(x_1+dx_1)}{f(x_2+dx_2)}$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

As mentioned above, I am trying to take the first-order Taylor expansion of $$\frac{f(x_1+dx_1)}{f(x_2+dx_2)}$$ My attempt is

$$\frac{f(x_1) + \frac{df}{dx_1}\Delta x_1}{f(x_2) + \frac{df}{dx_2}\Delta x_2}$$ where I've just taken 'separate' Taylor expansions on the numerator and denominator. I don't think this is right? It'd be great if someone could point me in the right direction, thanks!

EDIT - POSSIBLE ANSWER:

This seems like a plausible attempt:

$$ [f(x_1 + dx_1)][f(x_2 + dx_2)]^{-1} $$

Taking Taylor expansions, we have

$$ \left[f(x_1) + \frac{df}{dx_1} \Delta x_1 \right]\left[ f(x_2) + \frac{df}{dx_2}\Delta x_2 \right]^{-1} $$

$$ \left[f(x_1) + \frac{df}{dx_1} \Delta x_1 \right] \frac{1}{f(x_2)} \left[ 1 + \frac{1}{f(x_2)} \frac{df}{dx_2}\Delta x_2 \right]^{-1} $$

Then taking the binomial expansion for the 3rd term in the product, we get

$$\frac{1}{f(x_2)} \left[ f(x_1) + \frac{df}{dx_1} \Delta x_1 \right] \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{f(x_2)} \frac{df}{dx_2} \Delta x_2 \right]$$

We can then expand and get rid of the $\Delta x_1\Delta x_2$ term because they are small terms. I eventually get

$$\frac{f(x_1) - \frac{f(x_1)}{f(x_2)}\frac{df}{dx_2}\Delta x_2 + \frac{df}{dx_1}\Delta x_1}{f(x_2)}$$

Comment: With $dx_1=dx_2$?

Comment: Not necessarily, no.

Comment: Please correct the typos after "we get".

Comment: I'm sorry, where's the typo? The line right after 'we get' (i.e. 2nd expression from bottom) seems good to me. Though I should say the two lines aren't equal, but approximately equal.

Comment: Yeah, you modified this line after my comment (why these games, one wonders). Now the mistake shows on the next line, after "I eventually get".

Comment: I changed it to (1 - something)^(-1) without thinking before, then reverted back to my original answer (what is there now) when I took a second look. I'm not playing any 'games', thanks. 

You're right in regards to the error in the last line. I actually re-framed my question from what I actually have on paper so that I'm not getting the answer 'for free'. What I had above (last line) works for me, but not without the other caveats that only applies to me and not to the problem in general.

Comment: When I meant that "what I had above (last line) works for me", I meant in terms of the 'mistake' I had before. I've edited the line to be representative of the posed problem.

Answer (score 1):

For (my) convenience, I changed notation and, in the same spirit as in your edit, I considered $$\frac{f(x+a)}{f(y+b)}$$ and used Taylor expansions around $a=0$ and $b=0$.

So, $$f(x+a)=f(x)+a f'(x)+O\left(a^2\right)$$ $$f(y+b)=f(y)+b f'(y)+O\left(b^2\right)$$ $$\frac 1{f(y+b)}=\frac{1}{f(y)}-\frac{b f'(y)}{f(y)^2}+O\left(b^2\right)$$ which make $$\frac{f(x+a)}{f(y+b)}=\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}-\frac{b f(x) f'(y)}{f(y)^2}+O\left(b^2\right)\right)+a
   \left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(y)}-\frac{f'(x) f'(y)
   b}{f(y)^2}+O\left(b^2\right)\right)+O\left(a^2\right)$$ Ignoring the $O\left(a^2\right)$ and $O\left(b^2\right)$ terms, this reduces to $$\frac{f(x+a)}{f(y+b)}\approx \frac{\left(f(x)+a f'(x)\right) \left(f(y)-b f'(y)\right)}{f(y)^2}\tag 1$$ $$\frac{f(x+a)}{f(y+b)}\approx \frac{f(x) f(y)+a f(y) f'(x)-b f(x) f'(y)-a b f'(x) f'(y) }{f(y)^2}$$ Now, if we neglect the cross term $$\frac{f(x+a)}{f(y+b)}\approx \frac{f(x) f(y)+a f(y) f'(x)-b f(x) f'(y) }{f(y)^2}$$ which is exactly your last formula.

May I confess that I would prefer $(1)$ as an approximation ?

Comment: I take it you meant that you took Taylor expansions "around x = 0 and y = 0" instead? I didn't think of using the $O$ notation - thanks for adding that in.

Comment: @AstroMase. No, the expansions are done around $a=0$ and $b=0$ Remember that $x=x_1$, $y=x_2$, $a=\Delta x_1$, $b=\Delta x_2$ the lhs being my notations and the rhs your notations. I apologize for having changed notations; being almost blind, I try to avoid things with more than a single character (when I can do it). Cheers.